# Removing old accounts from the Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode-organizer

When I open up the Xcode 4 Organizer and select Devices, and then choose a team name, I see several duplicate people on there. Some of those have a yellow warning icon which indicates they are invalid. There is no way to select them in order to delete them.

How do I delete the extra accounts on this screen?

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete these accounts, do the following:

1. Launch Keychain Access.
2. Select Certificates on the left (not My Certificates).
3. Delete any certificate that is invalid, or doesn't have a private key associated with it. Certificates that have private keys associated with them have a triangle to their left, similar to those seen here next to the 2nd and 4th options in the list:

   [image]
4. Restart Xcode.
5. When you launch the Organizer, it will recreate an single entry (and corresponding certificate) for each developer on the team.

Answer (score 0):

First remove certificates from KeyChain Access as shown in Answer by @senseful.

After that remove Accounts from: XCode preference -> Accounts -> Select account -> click "-" Icon on left bottom side of dialogue box

[image: XCode Preferences]

[image: Accounts]